# How to retrieve td input textbox value from table with jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to get value of

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmount" CssClass="classTotalAmount number" Columns="8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

from table.

In aspx file:

```
<table id="tblitems" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="additemtb">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Item Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Item Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Unit Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Qty
            </th>
            <th>
                UOM
            </th>
            <th>
                Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Minimal Order Qty
            </th>
            <th>
                FOC
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:190px;">

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_ItemCode" CssClass="classItemCode readonly" Columns="8" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap">
                <input type="text" id="txtunitprice" name="txtunitprice" class="classUnitPrice number readonly" style="width:50px;" />
                <input type="hidden" id="hidunitprice" name="hidunitprice" class="classUnitPrice2" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblCurrency" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency" />
                <input type="hidden" id="hidcurrencyid" name="hidcurrencyid" class="classCurrencyID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtqty" name="txtqty" class="classQty number decimaltextbox" style="width:50px" onkeyup="calculateAmount(this);" onblur="minamt(this);calculateAmount(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_UOM" CssClass="classUOM readonly" Columns="5" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_Amount" CssClass="classAmount number readonly" Columns="8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtminorderqty" name="txtminorderqty" class="minorderqty number readonly" style="width:60px;background:none;border:none;font-weight:bold;color:Red;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:1px">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkFOC" name="chkFOC" class="classFOC btnborder" onclick="calculateFOC(this);" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hidFOC" id="hidFOC" class="classFOC2" value="false" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:90px;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="copy" onclick="copyRow(this);">Copy</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete" onclick="removeRow(this);">delete</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add" onclick="addRows(this)">add</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="darkgray">
                <span class="classOverBudget chinese" >Purchase Order Amount is over limited budget.</span>
            </td>
            <td class="darkgray" style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap">Total Amount</td>
            <td class="darkgray" >
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmount" CssClass="classTotalAmount number" Columns="8" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency3" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" class="darkgray">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In jQuery:

```
function removeRow(name) {
        if ($("#tblitems tr").length <= 3) return;
        $(name).parent().parent().remove();
        $(".promotion-container").css("height", $("#left").innerHeight() - 42 + "px"); 
         var total= $(name).parent().parent().siblings().find(".classTotalAmount input:textbox").val();        

        alert(total); // only show undefined, not give value

        $(name).parent().parent().find(".classAmount").each(function() {
            total -= parseFloat($(this).val());     

        });    

        $(name).parent().parent().find(".classTotalAmount").val(total.toFixed(2)); 

        FormActionControl();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of your text box by getting it using the rendered ID

```
jQuert('#<%=txtTotalAmount.ClientID').val()
```

so your code will be done

```
var total= $('#<%=txtTotalAmount.ClientID').val();
```